# Should i run UDLD with spanning tree?

Tags: udld, spanning-tree

Can spanning tree and UDLD be run together, and if so, is this a good idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

UDLD is generally run on fibre media, it is not required on UTP due to the use of Fast Link Pulse which is already monitoring link status.

[This page has a very good explanation of the various L2 protections available](http://ericleahy.com/index.php/bpdu-guard-bpdu-filter-root-guard-loop-guard-udld/). Here is an excerpt specifically regarding UDLD:

> UDLD is used to detect if a link is only available in one direction,
>   for example half the fibre is disconnected. UDLD performs this check
>   faster than STP will bring the port in to a fowarding state. That
>   means if you have UDLD and STP enabled then UDLD will prevent STP from
>   bringing a port in to a state where it will forward traffic to
>   nowhere.
>
> A unidirectional link occurs when traffic is transmitted between
>   neighbors in one direction only. Unidirectional Link Detection is a
>   Layer 2 protocol. UDLD performs tasks that Layer 1  mechanisms, such
>   as auto negotiation, cannot perform. When UDLD and auto-negotiation
>   are enabled, both Layer 1 and Layer 2 detections work together to
>   prevent physical and logical unidirectional connections and the
>   malfunctioning of other protocols. Unidirectional links can cause 
>   spanning-tree topology loops. UDLD enables devices to detect when a
>   unidirectional link exists and also to shut down the affected
>   interface. UDLD is useful on a fiber ports to prevent  network issues
>   resulting in miswiring at the patch panel causing the link to be in
>   up/up status but the BPDUs are lost.
>
> With UDLD enabled, the switch periodically sends UDLD protocol packets
>   to its neighbor and expects the packets to be echoed back before a
>   predetermined timer expires. If the timer  expires, the switch
>   determines the link to be unidirectional and shuts down the port. If
>   messages are not received within the timeout interval (45 seconds),
>   the port is disabled. The messages are sent out every default
>   interval, which is 15 seconds.
>
> The 45 seconds it takes to detect a unidirectional link and errdisable
>   the port is less than the 50 seconds it would take for STP to
>   transition the port to a Forwarding state, which is based on 20
>   seconds for Max Age + 30 seconds for Listening and Learning. This
>   prevents a loop that would otherwise be caused if STP transitioned the
>   port into the Forwarding state because of a lack of received BPDUs.

So in summary, yes they can be run together and on fibre links they *should* be run together.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's a good idea to run both as they protect you from different failures. If UDLD is not supported on both sides you can use LACP as a poor man's UDLD (between Cisco and Juniper for example) or you could even use Ethernet OAM LFM.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely.  There are many failure modes in spanning tree related to uni directional traffic that UDLD is able to detect and make sure the network continues operating correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, UDLD is very important, especially on fiber links.

I would recommend both sides of the link be configured using 'udld aggressive' mode if your devices support it.

Answer (score 1):

I only use it on copper ports where there is another L1 media between endpoints, the usual culprit of this is a fibre media converter.